# Twitter data can't be parsed from a text file

Tags: python, pandas, twitter

I am collecting twitter data in txt file via streaming and I use this file for filtering and various queries using ipython notebook. I find that sometimes when I have a heavy data file the command gets stuck somewhere around 'text' a category in twitter data. I need the way around to handle the data so that I am not stuck. I am pasting below what happens.

```
tweets_ISIS = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text('ISIS', tweets))
```

Here is the output:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call   last)
 <ipython-input-34-444b712d99dc> in <module>()
 ----> 1 tweets_ISIS = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text('ISIS', tweets))

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
    2167             values = lib.map_infer(values, lib.Timestamp)
    2168 
  -> 2169         mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
      2170         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
      2171             from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

   pandas/src/inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:62578)()

     <ipython-input-34-444b712d99dc> in <lambda>(tweet)
          ----> 1 tweets_ISIS = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text('ISIS', tweets))

      <ipython-input-33-0ee00dabf341> in word_in_text(word, text)
         1 def word_in_text(word, text):
       2     word = word.lower()
   ----> 3     text = text.lower()
      4     match = re.search(word, text)
        5     if match:

    /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in            __getattr__(self, name)
     2358                 return self[name]
    2359             raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" %
 -> 2360                                  (type(self).__name__, name))
    2361 
     2362     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

   AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'lower
```

I defined as follows `import re`:

```
    def word_in_text(word, text):
        word = word.lower()
          text = text.lower()
         match = re.search(word, text)
         if match:
            return True
             return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `tweets` when I think your intention was to use `tweet`. You are passing the DataFrame to `word_in_text()` rather than passing the input of the lambda function to `word_in_text()`. Try:

```
tweets_ISIS = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text('ISIS', tweet))
```

Also, is `apply()` the right function to use here? Based on the limited context, it seems that `map()` might the be proper choice to run `word_in_text()` on each value in the `text` Series, but I can't tell for sure without something more complete and reproducible.

Comment: It still yielded the same result

Comment: Did you try `tweets_ISIS = tweets['text'].map(lambda tweet: word_in_text('ISIS', tweet))` (with `map`)? I don't understand how the `tweet` input parameter to your lambda function could be a dataframe inside of a map... You could try putting a `print(text)` inside of `word_in_text ` to see what the lambda function is passing to `word_in_text`.

Answer (score 0):

I defined as follows `import re`

```
    def word_in_text(word, text):
        word = word.lower()
          text = text.lower()
         match = re.search(word, text)
         if match:
            return True
             return False
```